# Joomla 2.5 URI Key authenticatio

Tags: php, url, authentication, joomla, uri

It used to be possible for user to login to joomla via key,value pairs in the uri of a page. I'm not sure if our site used a component for this or if it is natively possible in Joomla 2.5. For example, the link used to work like this:

http://joomla-site.com/index.php?user=&passw=fd7fc823ec0f49c4624a27643bdcda5:2Wvb6aQcM1VzEwnDcD2KlymMdD0veosP&option=com_componenttoview&view=viewtoview&Itemid=170

However, now it doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions or knowledge which could help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have found some IP-based authorization extensions in the authorization section of Joomla Extensions site, but this is not a real answer to the question, only a potential solution. However, it is not an ideal solution for my problem.

Edit: 9/13

Also apparently we can authenticate based on MAC address using PHP or Java. Here is a php snippet which is supposed to capture the MAC address, which could then be stored and used for authentication. 
    It’s really not hard, and you can restrict any script to a certain MAC network adapter address. Here’s how to do it (Source: http://www.artviper.net/wp/programming-php-ajax-mysql/retrieve-local-mac-address-via-php/)

```
function getMac(){
          exec("ipconfig /all", $output);
          foreach($output as $line){
              if (preg_match("/(.*)Physical Address(.*)/", $line)){
                  $mac = $line;
                  $mac = str_replace("Physical Address. . . . . . . . . :","",$mac);
              }
          }
          return $mac;
      }
$mac = getMac();
$mac = trim($mac);
```

Maybe it only works on windows machines according to the source linked above. I guess I will make an extension when I have time and add it to the Joomla Extensions page.